# asp.net jquery ajax post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm trying to call an asp.net method using jquery/ajax from a button click on a modal dialog window. But all I seem to get is and alert saying "error". I've seen many similar examples for this online but I can't seem to get it to work. The page/method I'm calling (newcall.aspx/savenote) is the same page as all the jquery/ajax etc.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks,

```
        var dlg = jQuery("#dialog2").dialog({
            bgiframe: false,
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 410,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            show: 'Transfer',
            hide: 'Transfer',
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true,
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Save": function() {
                    var txtnote = document.getElementById("<%=txtNote.ClientID %>").value;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "newcall.aspx/savenote",
                        data: txtnote,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",                            
                        success: function(msg) {
                            alert(msg);
                        },        
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }

        );
```

Code behind method:( At the moment I'm just returning "ok")

```
Public Function savenote() As String
    Return "ok"
End Function
```

Comment: Change `alert(textStatus);` to `alert(errorThrown);`, what do you get?

Comment: Missing WebMethod attribute - how do I add this?

Comment: use the Webmethod Attribute. Put [WebMethod] above the savenote() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the WebMethod attribute, declare the page method as `Shared`, and match the data you're sending with the method's signature.  This is how you should change your server-side method:

```
<WebMethod()>_
Public Shared Function savenote() As String
  Return "ok"
End Function
```

You may get away with not changing your data parameter, but probably not since it's invalid JSON.  Try changing your data parameter to just `{}` for now.  When you're ready to start passing txtnote in to your server-side method, you'll want to pass that as `{txtnote: 'Your note string here'}`.